# Can Spectral Radius be a Norm on $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $n > 1$ be an integer. For each $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, let  $||A || = \rho(A)$, the spectral radius of $A$. Does this turn $M_{n×n}(\mathbb{C})$ into a normed space?

I think the answer must be no and here is my counterexample, but I'm not sure about it.

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$Spec(B)=\{0\}$, however $B\neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct.  Since it is possible to have $\rho(A) = 0$ with $A \ne 0$, this is not a norm.

Answer (score 2):

Moreover, in the OP example we have $\rho(B) = \rho(B^t) = 0$, while $\rho(B+B^t) = 1$, so $\rho$ is not subadditive, hence not even a seminorm.